# How to decrypt HTTPS (ECDHE) data?

Tags: php, encryption, https, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I am trying to understand how exactly HTTPS works and doing a little practical tests.

I have a data captured from HTTPS communication encrypted by TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.

If I understood it right, client during the TLS handshake creates a master key, which is then encrypted using server's public key and sent to server. This master key (as a plain text) is then used as a symmetric key for encrypting ongoing communication. Is this correct?

If yes, how to decrypt the data, if I know the master key?

It sounded pretty easy to me at first, so I just wrote this script

```
$masterKey = '8ef36f0eb2c10ea6142693374f6c5c7ae65eee5f6bd45bd1990b08e6c144227382726496b795d62284bd8c6c0cadbbdb';

$someRandomEncryptedData = '170303001D314A69C7DF95E07AAF51FBDA01C178D45330BC902308DF8C418FA5B02B';

$sDecrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, pack('H*', $masterKey), pack('H*', $someRandomEncryptedData), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

echo $sDecrypted;
```

Then I notice that master key is 96 byte long (48 as binary string), which results to PHP warning as the key should be 256 bit (32 byte) long. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> client during the request creates a master key, which is then encrypted using server's public key and sent to server. This master key (as a plain text) is then used as a symmetric key for encrypting ongoing communication. Is this correct?

Well, all-in-all, No.

Because you are asking about DH and ECDH, which are Key Agreement protocols: the client does ***not*** generate a random key, encrypt it under the server's public key and then send it to the server. That's Key Transport (like RSA Key Transport), and ***not*** DH or ECDH. Key transport is going away in TLS 1.3.

There are two phases to TLS: key agreement and bulk transfer. The phases are not as well defined as in IPSec. When the client and server use DH or ECDH, they arrive at a `premaster_secret`. That's the shared secret drops out of Diffie-Hellman or Elliptic Curve  Diffie-Hellman.

They take the `premaster_secret`, they add a client random, a server random, and arrive at a `master_secret`. Then they take the `master_secret` and derive 6 symmetric keys from it:

- Client initial IV
- Client encryption key
- Client mac key
- Server initial IV
- Server encryption key
- Server mac key

Those keys are used to key a block or stream cipher.

If you notice, each side contributes to the `premaster_secret` - the client contributes `g^a` and the server contributes `g^b`. Then each side contributes to the `master_secret` through nonces - the client random and the server random.

The reason there's two contributions from both sides is transport schemes, like RSA Key Transport, don't allow the server to contribute to the `premaster_secret`. The server has to wait until the derivation of the `master_secret` to contribute to the key material via a nonce.

So the progression is `premaster_secret` to `master_secret` to 6 session keys. I'm not sure where the master key is...

---

> If yes, how to decrypt the data, if I know the master key?

I think its usually easier to just plug it into Wireshark if you have the master key. The Wireshark wiki talks about a master key (though I don't know what it is - there's a `premaster_secret` and `master_secret`). See the Wireshark wiki for [Secure Socket Layer (SSL)](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).

---

> It sounded pretty easy to me at first, so I just wrote this script

Yeah... :) Check out RFC 5246. That's [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246). Then let's talk about easy :)

---

> Then I notice that master key is 96 byte long (48 as binary string)

96 bytes is the output of the PseudoRandom Function (PRF). Check out RFC 5246, page 13.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it wouldn't be that easy. I was just reading some documentation, but it was probably outdated, as it was using some different key exchange mechanism. That's what confused me. What I want to achieve is that just by reading the raw packets and knowing all keys I need to know, I want to be able to decrypt the text by myself using some homemade script from scratch. I just like to know  how things work at their lowest possible level .. ;)